# Rest Assured Mock Mvc not picking up custom Object Mapper

Tags: java, spring-mvc, rest-assured

I have a very similar problem to this post: [Rest Assured doesn't use custom ObjectMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43127485/rest-assured-doesnt-use-custom-objectmapper)

However, I am using slightly different configurations/models and the provided answer did not solve my problem.

When running the mock mvc test, my custom ObjectMapper config is not getting picked up.  I have tried attaching this config class to the RestAssuredMockMvc, but it still seems to not pick this up when the standalone setup fires.

Any ideas?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public abstract class BaseClassForContractTests {

@Autowired
Controller controller;

@Before
public void setup() {

    RestAssuredMockMvc.config = RestAssuredMockMvcConfig.config().objectMapperConfig(
            ObjectMapperConfig.objectMapperConfig().jackson2ObjectMapperFactory(new Jackson2ObjectMapperFactory() {
                @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
                @Override
                public ObjectMapper create(Class cls, String charset) {
                    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                    objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
                    objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
                    //objectMapper.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
                    //objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE, true);
                    return objectMapper;
                }
            })
    );

    RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(controller);

}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I have setup object mapper with `RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup` and it worked for me.

```
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter = new
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.setObjectMapper(new ObjectMapper()));
RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(
     MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(yourcontroller)
             .setMessageConverters(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter)
);
```

[The full solution is described in this article](https://medium.com/@vicusbass/datetime-serialization-in-spring-tests-5d31ccd025c)

Comment: This helped me fix my issue exactly like I needed - +1 ! Thanks @shubham-gulati

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it was something stupid/simple.  If anyone has this issue with no configs getting picked up, you should be using RestAssuredMockMvc.**webAppContextSetup**(context); instead of standaloneSetup.  All you have to do is @Autowire a webAppContext.